# How do I mask serial-getty@ttyAMA0 service in yocto

Tags: yocto

I am trying to mask the serial-getty@ttyAMA0 service from within a recipe.
How Can I achieve this?

I tried creating a  initscripts bbappend file with this addition as shown below

```
pkg_postinst_${PN}{
    systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
}
```

But this gives me an error. `Could not invoke Dnf`

I have run out of Ideas

Comment: Did you specify the dependy with `systemd-systemctl-native` ?

Comment: Nope I did not... However I am getting around this issue by using `systemctl disable serial-getty@.service`. So you are suggesting to perform a `RDEPENDS = systemd-systemctl-native`

Comment: I suggest to use 'DEPENDS' instead. As mentioned in the reference manual, it lists build-time dependencies which is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Correct solution is to control SERIAL_CONSOLES variable in local.conf. systemd-serialgetty parses it and creates corresponding systemd service files. Simple

```
SERIAL_CONSOLES = ""
```

can do the trick for you.